# File sharing via USB NIC not possible

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, network-adapter

### Environment

- Win 10 (1709) 64 bit
- Dell Latitude 7390
- Dell Dock WD15 providing networking (Realtek USB GbE Family Controller)

### Description of issue

The notebook behaves as expected network-wise, everything network-related works, incoming and outgoing, except that other computers can not access the network share I created on this Win10 machine.

File sharing is not possible when network is provided by docking station.
I tried using windows clients (7 and 10, but forgot the error message) and I tried using 
Linux which throws

```
Jun 12 14:53:10 MYMACHINE kernel: [  813.358141] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Jun 12 14:53:10 MYMACHINE kernel: [  813.358234] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -111
```

**However file sharing is possible without issues when I plug the network cable directly into the notebook.** This is independent of the TCP settings on the NICs, i.e. I tried fixed and DHCP addresses on both interfaces but the issue remains.

Scanning the notebook for open ports shows

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
111/tcp  open     rpcbind
135/tcp  open     msrpc
515/tcp  open     printer
1024/tcp open     kdm
1110/tcp filtered nfsd-status
3389/tcp open     ms-wbt-server
5357/tcp open     wsdapi
8100/tcp open     xprint-server
```

... where I'm missing port 445, but at least that's consistent with `netstat -ano|findstr 445` which shows that port 445 is only opened on loopback and TCP6

```
C:\Users\myuser>netstat -ano|findstr 445
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN         4
  TCP    10.11.97.163:58737     10.11.10.101:445       HERGESTELLT     4
  TCP    10.11.97.163:58742     10.11.10.121:445       HERGESTELLT     4
  TCP    10.11.97.163:58744     10.11.10.127:445       HERGESTELLT     4
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 ABHÖREN         4
```

### Previous research / ideas

- checked if SMB version on cliens is the cause -> no, older SMB versions are permitted
- Windows firewall is disabled
- Kaspersky Endpoint Security completely disabled
- tried DHCP and fixed IPs
- disabled checksum offloading for NIC
- updated firmware on WD15 dock
- `smbclient` on linux: `protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET`
- Debugging info from CIFS (obtained through `echo 7 > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI`): `Status code returned 0xc000019c NT_STATUS_FS_DRIVER_REQUIRED`

At least I'm not alone, others describe the same issue: [Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a1c60d39-7a28-46dc-9de0-0f934a4ca628/port-445-smb-closed-always-after-reboot?forum=win10itpronetworking)

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I have no problems whatsoever with my Precision 5520 and the WD15 dock. Try on Linux with `smbclient`, it can probably provide better diagnostic info.

Comment: added the info to the list "previous research"

Comment: Alrighty, so, did you run packet sniffers on both ends of the connection?

Comment: Not yet, will do and post back

Comment: I got this working fiddeling with the rules of the deactivated (!) Defender Firewall somehow, but now it stopped working again.Sniffing is not an option as this is a corporate device.

Comment: Yeah well if you can’t diagnose the problem how are you supposed to solve it? Educated guessing just doesn’t cut it with complex technology.

Comment: That's why I'm asking here - perhaps someone had the same issue bout could properly diagnose it and share her / his wisdom. Isn't this what SE is all about? ;-)